# Having an issue launching IIS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have received a project from a git repository, where there are clearly some elements missing, however, whenever I attempt to start this application using IIS Express I am getting this error.

[image: Error]

this is a web application using an API.

this is the code for the launchsettings.json.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53563/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Clockwork.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried researching this error on google, and most, if not all of the articles say to disable encryption on the iis express folder, however, I am using windows 10 home edition so there is no EFS encryption open. whenever I right click the iis express folder, go to advanced settings, the encryption option is greyed out.

it is worth noting that for some reason I do not have a .vs/config/ folders in the project.

as shown here.

[image: Folders]

If you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: looks more like you have some random file lock to me. Have you tried restarting VS and or your computer?

Comment: I have tried both restarting VS and my computer. No Luck